# Getting "ValueError:Shapes (None, 2) and (None, 1) are incompatible" when using more than one value for "metrics" in model.compile

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, auc

In model.compile we can pass multiple metrics values like so -

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
          optimizer='sgd',
          metrics=[metrics.mae, metrics.categorical_accuracy]) \\or like 
          metrics=['mae', 'categorical_accuracy']
```

However, when I am adding more than one values in metrics I am getting -

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 2) and (None, 1) are incompatible
```

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import transformers
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
MODEL_NAME = 'distilbert-base-uncased'
BATCH_SIZE = 8
N_EPOCHS = 3

tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

train_encodings = tokenizer(list(X_train.values),
                        truncation=True, 
                        padding=True)
test_encodings = tokenizer(list(X_test.values),
                       truncation=True, 
                       padding=True)

train_dataset = 
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(train_encodings),list(y_train.values)))

test_dataset = 
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(test_encodings),list(y_test.values)))

test_dataset2 = test_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).take(1000).batch(16)

model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

optimizerr = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5)

losss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizerr,
          loss=losss,
          metrics=['accuracy','AUC'])

print("Evaluate Base model on test data")
results = model.evaluate(test_dataset2)
print("test loss, test acc:", results)
```

This is where I am getting the error.

On the other hand, when model.compile is like -

```
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizerr,
          loss=losss,
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

the code is running fine.

I need to evaluate several metrics like AUC, precision score, recall score, etc.
but, when I am adding any of those I am getting the above error. How can I fix this?

Edit:

I am getting the same error when I using -

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizerr,
          loss=losss,
          metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives()])
```

I am also getting the same error when I am using any other metric other that 'accuracy'

Comment: what is the shape of `y_test`?

Comment: the shape of y_test is (5000,)

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia the testdataset2 that I have used for evaluation is : <BatchDataset shapes: ({input_ids: (None, 512), attention_mask: (None, 512)}, (None,)), types: ({input_ids: tf.int32, attention_mask: tf.int32}, tf.int32)>  you can get an idea of the shape from this. I am getting the error on the model.evaluate function

Comment: what is printed if you run `tf.shape(model.predict(test_dataset2))`?

Comment: when I am using it after compiling the model with tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives() metric, i am getting - "ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (TFSequenceClassifierOutput(loss=None, logits=array([[-0.0398448 ,  0.08726611],
       [ 0.01140752,  0.08392248],
       [-0.01814505,  0.07899118],
       ..., dtype=float32), hidden_states=None, attentions=None)) with an unsupported type (<class 'transformers.modeling_tf_outputs.TFSequenceClassifierOutput'>) to a Tensor.

Comment: and when I am running the suggested like with metric = 'accuracy', I am getting the same error.

Comment: sorry i meant `tf.shape(model.predict(train_encodings)) `

Comment: I am getting the following error - ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'transformers.tokenization_utils_base.BatchEncoding'>, <class 'NoneType'>